# What are the musical instruments that have the sounding range that has at least all notes on this range A#1-C5?

Tags: instruments, instrument-range

What are the musical instruments that have the sounding range that has at least all notes on this range A#1-C5?
The instrument can go up to C6, or down to c0, it just need to have all the notes on A#1-C5 (including C5 and A#1).

Most pdfs I can find on internet with it a pretty basic, and dont have enought instruments. On Wolfram alpha website, its possible to find the range of instruments, many different ones, but you actually need to write down the instruments you know to check their range

Comment: I am curious: why are you asking for instruments with this specific range? Are you writing some music that requires it?

Answer (score 9):

There is this [nice chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(music)) on Wikipedia that show the range of many instruments, probably more than a composer would typically use to compose music. Harps, Pianos, Bassoons, Contra-alto Clarinets, Tenor Wagner Tubas, Bass Trombones, Baritone Horns and Euphoniums are example of those that you need.

By the way, some musical notation programs like [Sibelius](http://www.sibelius.com/home/index_flash.html) is able to highlight which notes are out of range for the associated instrument: if I wrote a C8 on a Bass Trombone line, it would automatically highlight the note in red. Furthermore, these programs normally contain at least a thousand instruments for you to choose, and I guess that's more than you ever need

Answer (score 5):

A "proper" Bayan runs in its core right hand keyboard from E2 to G7.  Using registers with the bass reed would give you E1 to G6.  Range in the left hand is E1 to C#6 I think.

The lefthand side of most converter accordions actually runs from E1 to C#6.  For the right side to have similar range, you need to use a chromatic button accordion however: piano accordions are quite more modest in range.  Most large piano accordions (41 keys) run from F3 to A6 in the keyboard (different registers extending range one octave below and up), with the largest converter accordions (45 keys) going from E3 to C7 in the right hand.

My Morino Artiste button accordion runs in its righthand keyboard from A2 to A#7.  Using the bass reed, that gives me A1 to A#6.  That just barely meets your low range requirements and the Morino Artiste are close to the largest ranged "Western" button accordions.  So reaching that range with the right hand of a chromatic button accordion will require specifically looking for large-ranged instruments: the "usual" will not go down far enough.

Answer (score 2):

Malmark Bellcraftsmen manufacture sets of handbells covering 7 1/2 octaves, from G1 through C9.  Though most are cast and lathe-turned bronze, the lowest pitched bells are cast in aluminum for ease in handling.  They are stretched-tuned to A440 and fall within 10/100th's of a semitone tolerance.  Check their website for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Bass English concertina will cover this range; a full 48 key bass English will have a compass from G1 - G5.

They are rare and wonderful beats, but examples do crop up for sale every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers' suggestions, most Otamatones have the required range you seek. It's a japanese instrument that looks like this:

[image: le otamatone]

It is played similarly to a string instrument in terms of fingering, and sounds very strange, but looks very funny to play.